# Is it possible to design this kind of Master Page in Sharepoint?

Tags: 2013, master-page, custom-masterpage, design

I want to develop this kind of MasterPage for a Sharepoint Project.

https://designsmaz.com/responsive-admin-dashboard-templates/

Is it possible? anyone have did it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can [create and design the master page](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/steps-to-create-custom-master-page-in-sharepoint-2013-using-visual-studio/) like [this](https://designsmaz.com/responsive-admin-dashboard-templates/).

- You can apply styles on existing classes and apply custom scripts.
- Example: [Quick launch (Left navigation) styles in SharePoint 2013](http://akashkarda.blogspot.in/2014/05/quick-launch-styles-in-sharepoint-2013.html)
- You can also change look and feel of default sharepoint `topsuitebar`, `sideNavBox`, `ContentBox` by applying styles on them.
- [Where and how do you start branding SharePoint](http://en.share-gate.com/blog/where-and-how-to-start-branding-sharepoint)
- [SharePoint Design Manager - Convert HTML to Master Page](https://bniaulin.wordpress.com/2012/07/18/sharepoint-2013-design-manager-convert-html-to-master-page/)